# url rewriting to redirect www to non www on https

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, ssl

I just changed my website http to https. I'll already redirected http to https version. I also want to redirect www version to non www. 
So far couldn't succeed it.

http://www.domain.com => https://domain.com

https://www.domain.com => https://domain.com

Here is the .htaccess file;

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
        redirect 301 /makale /sozluk
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
        RewriteRule ^(.*)\.[\d]+\.(css|js)$ $1.$2 [L]

        RewriteCond %{HTTPS ^www.sporapp.com$ [NC]
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://sporapp.com/$1 [R=301,L]

        RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
        # This checks to make sure the connection is not already HTTPS
        RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [NC,QSA,L]
</ifModule>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove this bit:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS ^www.sporapp.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://sporapp.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
# This checks to make sure the connection is not already HTTPS
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

And add this just under the `RewriteEngine On`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.sporapp\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://sporapp.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

You need to have the redirecting happening **before** you rewrite, otherwise the request gets changed before it gets redirected.

Also, you have mod_alias directives which will interfere with the rewrite to `/index.php`:

```
redirect 301 /makale /sozluk
```

Should be:

```
RewriteRule ^makale/(.*)$ /sozluk/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: didn't work. https://www.sporapp.com/ www still stays so I get warning from browser because ssl is just for sporapp.com not for www.sporapp.com

Comment: @tylerdurden you will get that warning no matter what. The SSL negotiation happens **when you establish the connection**, and that's *before* any request is ever sent to the server. So you need to buy a wildcard cert if you want this to work.

Comment: ohh i see, after I click ok it redirected me to non www version. so money talks :) thanks man!